# How to extract all data keys and values in a nested python dict

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON response from an API call in python, this is of dict type and I need to extract all the keys and values by traversing through the nested dictionary.
I need some help to achieve this, what could be the best approach to check whether an item in the primary dict is another dict or just a key with a single value and not another dict.

```
{'html_attributions': [],
 'next_page_token': 'CrQEJAIAAO1gjIXdvnDjB40bRlRk9xUvHVqB_ZeYxmscrvINB13WdRTHfCoNorfeyJIc8yiW07HzrnxlU90hFiX0hn2Pe30iIeL5d8FBwBUjhC483L0jCdx7s0b4TY85rQnghHoa0lPKDSMRMDBedJZCaMbn-lWqpDdvZtakJLuZpIYjw8Q0R6aGsmcej5oWS0xZ6ovsoRz-coicPea_1lDeDVNFkae3SDGtJ3p2WgXu6vzhfUowCi4K9vUOP2WT_e0Q_UUrP0X1ASQMN4kMh3ibcbOXMGHoi4MkpYe1B2tmfdN5vSkH929o6FbXwd7aciZWswFnq1rmARV4FSaL8fbtyX0juDddOP4g4NcVi6MnCXRVw23S61d-Pu3X85gc-dIXqigcCPnhOKVmqG3FdZC_fDTqgB3nXBmHOETHLjdHLa0BfMT-mqamZ2Zr--sBa05JEgbb8YquLsgS4rb-dLJj4U0Gq0jI7BNstRt0Dszy8bj9admRe9xYFGUlIs7ex9yCAilhJ4j4U91FEi4Po89sHguxkpuRGEQv88whgnfvTLCg0YbA71DPv7OhfR4PwbdWk1n6ElUCOLHR5lWarWU4iAhPjNBKqnXethE32qVakubNU69EEgHu0Ojq87XkaGuWBV6qaiZKmJFkY1dUKNPv0udEmesu9MQP35jpXRRr7r_EaN5neWL57pmyXFAuzQuRxa-7CORw_Sa2FTiBRIxTcpz3gAAP5X3CCKctxkSb8DruZ2YGEhBMAnIESGWZXQDTnGKd-Xf2GhQjt_LI8xL1-V8hHdTL-lK2DHJWNw',
 'results': [{'formatted_address': 'University of Lagos, Akoka Rd, Yaba, Lagos, Nigeria',
   'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 6.5151087, 'lng': 3.3886033},
    'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 6.522969049999999,
      'lng': 3.394707349999999},
     'southwest': {'lat': 6.50730845, 'lng': 3.38207915}}},
   'icon': 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/school-71.png',
   'id': '6bd1760a7bca49e16e560fec68f6125c2440f5ca',
   'name': 'UNILAG Nigeria',
   'opening_hours': {'open_now': False},
   'photos': [{'height': 2988,
     'html_attributions': ['<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109021919043392669000">Austin Chikwado Ofor</a>'],
     'photo_reference': 'CmRaAAAA7HbCOQBhVUUOZZC6-P9I3a9BoSf5lAucLlrcBUQrOPJuKCjy2oW6iCu205Hl6h1vYBC8W50y70Mnw4owsxiQ7HfWWXSk8ZV3QMN-ObVXXdsjrZsP0NFlguInVpxJkqN7EhBPh-DsZG7xkKnzwmIJ784pGhT7Ty0D8XWfGBZh2ayHMpMsk5dwPw',
     'width': 5312}],
   'place_id': 'ChIJi5nvgOSMOxARRiBHB-xDQ7k',
   'plus_code': {'compound_code': 'G98Q+2C Lagos',
    'global_code': '6FR5G98Q+2C'},
   'rating': 4.4,
   'reference': 'ChIJi5nvgOSMOxARRiBHB-xDQ7k',
   'types': ['university', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment'],
   'user_ratings_total': 700},
```

-

```
data_list = data_df['geometry'][0]['location'].keys()

for x in list(data_list):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        print(x,data_list[x].values())
    else:
        print(x)
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the data you have along with some code that you've tried so people know what the problem is and what you've tried so they can improve upon it and help you

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have expanded the question with the examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json, pandas as pd
df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(json_data)['results'])
df.head()
```

I finally discovered a pandas json_normalize method which does the trick. Initially, I was building a nested conditional to extract all the required feature, which could be a potential solution as well.

```
 item_keys = []


for item in data['results']:
    for i in item:
        if i not in item_keys:
            item_keys.append(i)

def print_cont(my_data):
    for x in item_keys:
        print(x)
        try:
            y = my_data[0][x]
            if isinstance(y,dict):
                for z in y:
                    k = y[z]
                    print(z,k)
                    if isinstance(k,dict):
                        for l in k:
                            print(l,k[l])
            else:
                print(y, type(y))
        except (AttributeError,TypeError,ValueError):
            print(x)
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

As, you did'nt provide any sample data, so i am assuming as HTTP Response object.
First you have to get the content from the object like this:

data_stream.read()

and then do iteration if response has nested json to get keys and values.

It will be great, if you provide content of the response object.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just provided the example in the edited question.